# Action not performed on click

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jbutton, actionlistener

With the following code I succeed in having a button in the correct cell in the JTable, but when I click on the button no action is performed. Any hnt?

```
            //Bottone salto cova
            JButton jump=new JButton(rCp.getGabbia().toString());
            jump.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                    jumpActionPerformed(evt);
                }

                private void jumpActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                    System.out.println("Bottone gabbia " + hatchlistijTable.getSelectedRow() + " " + hatchlistijTable.getSelectedColumn());
                }
                });
            //
            Object [] rowData = {i+1, // progressivo
                rCp.getNumeroCoppia(), // numero coppia
                rCp.getAnno(),
                //rCp.getGabbia(), // fecondo
                jump,
                data}; 
            ((javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel) hatchlistijTable.getModel()).addRow(rowData);
        //}
    }
    TableCellRenderer buttonRenderer = new JTableButtonRenderer();
    hatchlistijTable.getColumn(lingua_corrente.getString("jLabel8")).setCellRenderer(buttonRenderer);
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your code above just renders a button in the cell, it doesn't actually handle editing.  You need to implement a [TableCellEditor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableCellEditor.html) as well.  That editor is where you handle clicks make to the cell.

Answer (score 1):

[Table Button Column](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/12/table-button-column/) will handle the rendering/editing for you. You just provide the Action to execute when you click on the cell.